# Unable to upload all files using wildcards with psftp

Tags: windows, file-upload, sftp, putty, psftp

I wish to upload all files in `C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP` folder on my local Windows to remote SFTP server `myfolder` directory.

I have multiple issues running sftp on Windows and achieving the above.

Below is my command:

```
C:\putty\psftp.exe -b C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt -l myuser -pw mypass 10.8.44.86
```

Here is my `C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt` file:

```
mkdir myfolder
cd myfolder
lcd "C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP"
put "C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP\*.*"
```

I get "unable to open" error despite the file exists on my local Windows.

This works when I change `C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP\*.*` to `C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP\file1.txt`.

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>C:\putty\psftp.exe -b C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt -l myuser -pw mypass 10.8.44.86
Using username "myuser".
Pre-authentication banner message from server:
| EFT Server Enterprise 7.3.2.8
End of banner message from server
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Remote working directory is /
mkdir /myfolder: OK
Remote directory is now /myfolder
New local directory is C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP
local: unable to open C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP\*.*
```

Can you please suggest what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`put` does not support wildcards, you have to use [`mput`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mgetput):

```
lcd "C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP"
mput *.*
```